# Can a function return a value that is initialized in it?

Tags: c, function, scope

I really wonder why output is: 12 instead of 9 in following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 4, b = 2;
int c = 3;
int f(void);

int main(void) {
    printf("%3d\n", f());
    printf("%3d%3d%3d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}

int f(void) {
    int b, c;
    a = b = c = 4;
    return (a + b + c);
}
```

I mean since b and c local variables initialized as in the f function when function returned they no longer exist so they shouldn't be returned. Can anybody explain?

```
int k(void) {
    int d = 5;
return d;
}
```

Like the k function returns nothing, right?

Comment: The expresion (a+b+c) is calculed with the variables in that scope, all equal to 4. The integer result of the expression is what the function returns. It is not a macro...

Comment: Returning operates by value. The return value is a copy of the expression in the return statement. (Parameter passing works the same way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression, that `f` is not returning a single value but the entire expression `a + b + c` and that expression is evaluated in the calling function.  That is not what happens.

Inside the function `f`, the global `a` is set to 4 as is the locals `b` and `c`.  The values of each of those are added together resulting in the value 12, and that value is what is returned from the function.

Expressions are evaluated at the point they occur.

Comment: You've come really close to what i wonder .I've edited the question can you look at it?

Comment: @whysoserious The answer stands.  The value of the expression is evaluated ( in that case the expression is a single variable ) and the result of the expression is what is returned.  If you couldn’t return values based on local variables functions wouldn’t be of much use.

Comment: Then it looks like i misunderstood my textbook and when my assistant professor showed this function returns 12 in lecture i was frustrated. :)  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You made function `f` return summation of "values" of `a`, `b` and `c`, not variables themselves. By declaring variables named by `b` and `c` in function `f`, global variable `b` and `c` are shadowed by local variables, so any changes (like assigning 4 like you did) doesn't affect global variables with same names.